# MoveIt Forward kinematics

Tags: ros, forward-kinematics, moveit, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

does someone know how the forward kinematics is solved in MoveIt?

I know it is done with the getGlobalLinkTransform, but I don't know if this function solve it with a transformation matrix or in a otherwise.

Or is it only a measurement in the simulation model?

I need it for my Bachelor-Thesis to explain it a little bit.

Would be great if someone can help me out.

Best regards,
Jonas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295586/moveit-forward-kinematics/) by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the code you are looking for is [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/robot_state/src/robot_state.cpp#L591).

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0